# Maintain one view controller in Portrait and other in Landscape mode iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have an iOS app with 2 view controllers namely - `FirstViewController` and `SecondViewController`. **My window's rootViewController is UINavigationController**.

FirstViewController is supposed to work ONLY in portrait mode and SecondViewController ONLY in Landscape mode.

Searching all over Stackoverflow I found out that for iOS6 and above I have to create a category over `UINavigationController` and override `-supportedInterfaceOrientations`

**THE PROBLEM**

Starting from FirstViewController. Now my phone being in Portrait mode, I push SecondViewController, the view loads in portrait mode. Once I rotate my phone to be in landscape the view will rotate to landscape ( and from this point onwards will not return to portrait at all ).

When I pop back FirstViewController will be in Portrait again ( no matter what the orientation of the phone ).

I want that SecondViewController shouldn't be displayed in Portrait mode at all. I've racked my brains all day...cannot find a solution.

**APPDELEGATE**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc] init];

    self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

**FirstViewController**

```
- (IBAction)btnClicked:(id)sender
{
    SecondViewController *vc = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:NO];
}

#pragma mark - Rotation handlers
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

-(UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

**SecondViewController**

```
- (IBAction)btnClicked:(id)sender
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}



#pragma mark - Rotation handlers
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}

-(UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
}
```

**UINavigation Category**

```
@implementation UINavigationController (Rotation)

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    //return [self.topViewController shouldAutorotate];
    return YES;
}


-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return [self.topViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return [self.topViewController preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
}
@end
```

Comment: Mask the orientaion on the particular viewController.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's a bit late but here is what I figured.

While there are many solutions available for the case when FirstVC is Portrait and Second can be Portrait and Landscape, I couldn't find any good solution to this problem (First Portrait ONLY and Second Landscape ONLY). Here is what I did:

Embed both view controllers in their own Navigation Controllers. Create two new classes, say FirstNavController and SecondNavController subclassing UINavigationController. Use these as your navigation controllers. (If you are using StoryBoards, select the Navigation Controller, go to Identity Inspector and change 'Class' field).

Now, in FirstNavController, add:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate 
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations 
{ 
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

And in SecondNavController:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate 
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations 
{ 
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

You will have to present the SecondNavController modally.

Nothing needs to be done in your View Controllers. Make sure you add all required orientations in your application settings.

The only drawback of this method is that both views are not in the same navigation stack, as second was presented modally, so you won't see a back button. But you can add a cancel/dismiss button yourself and call dismissViewControllerAnimated in SecondVC.

Answer (score -3):

in my previous app i have done it

first you need to enable Portrait , Landscape left , Landscape right Orientation to project

**Now**

set below code to your FirstViewController

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait]; 
 }
      - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
 {
       return NO;
 }
```

set below code to your secondViewController

```
#define degreesToRadian(x) (M_PI * (x) / 180.0)


 @implementation UINavigationController (Rotation_IOS6)

 -(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
 return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] shouldAutorotate];
 }

 -(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
 {
   return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] supportedInterfaceOrientations];
 }

 @end
 @interface secondViewController ()

 @end

 @implementation secondViewController

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadian(90));

 }
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
   return YES;

 }

 - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
 {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
 }


  @end
```

Comment: By using transform like that I'm just fooling the system to believe that its in Landscape mode. If i show an UIAlertView it'll still be in Portrait Mode...

Comment: Would this work if we use navigation controller? I don't think so since affine transform on individual view would not transform the navigation bar, status bar etc.

Comment: by using above code all work fine UIAlertView will display as its in landscape mode check this screen shot of it http://imm.io/1lvY8